# HOw Do I split And rearrange My String?

Tags: java, split, text-files

I have a Text File that contains Names Starting with Surname and then First Name e.g.:

Surname Firstname

I need to Output them Starting with the First Name And then the Surname.e.g 
Firstname Surname

The code I have Outputs them in the right order. How Can I have them the reverse way? The code I have is:

```
public class SplitExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
         // TODO code application logic here
         FileInputStream fs3 = new FileInputStream("D:/Test.txt");
         BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs3));
         for(int c=0; c< 0; c++){
             br3.readLine();
         }
         String name = br3.readLine().trim();

         System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this `for(int c=0; c< 0; c++)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it, I made it a bit verbose for readability

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/test.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
Scanner lineScanner;

String surname = "";
String name = "";

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String delimiterInFile = " ";
    String lineInFile = scanner.nextLine();

    lineScanner = new Scanner(lineInFile).useDelimiter(delimiterInFile);

    if(lineScanner.hasNext()){
        surname = lineScanner.next();
    }
    if(lineScanner.hasNext()){
        name = lineScanner.next();
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", name, surname));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use String#split like this:

```
String[] arr = name.split(" ");` 
String revName = String.format("%s %s", arr[1], arr[0]);
```